# Codeigniter table library generates nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Model:

```
class Pagination_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function total_rows() {
    return $this->db->count_all('recipe');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 function browse()
    {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Finals/index.php/login/browse';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->pagination_model->total_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('recipe', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        //echo "<pre>";print_r( $data['records'] );die;
        $this->load->view('browse' , $data);
    }
```

My view:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>blablabla</title>
    <link href="../../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
           <h1><a href="#">grr</a></h1>
           <h2>by chief</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
           <ul>
               <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">My Recipes</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Browse Recipes</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="colOne">
           <div class="post">
              <div class="story">
             <h2>Results:</h2>
                <?php $this->table->generate($records); ?>
                <?php $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
             </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
           <p>Copyright &copy; </p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is what returns from print_r

```
 [result_id] => mysqli_result Object
            (
                [current_field] => 0
                [field_count] => 8
                [lengths] => 
                [num_rows] => 1
                [type] => 0
            )

        [result_array] => Array
            (
            )

        [result_object] => Array
            (
            )

        [custom_result_object] => Array
            (
            )

        [current_row] => 0
        [num_rows] => 1
        [row_data] =>
```

It does show 1 row, probaby because of my 1 per_page limit. But then, why is the row_data empty? should it print the row values?

plus, Even if the row_data was empty, when i typed pagination create_links() it shouldv atleast shown right? Is there any problem loading my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table::generate creates a string. You need to echo it.

```
            <?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
```

Comment: I ran into the same thing. Took me ages to see it then. Now it jumps out and smacks me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this, Bad way to describe the total to select all records and finding the number of rows in controller part, instead should be done in model.:

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('recipe')->num_rows();
```

To:

```
$config['total_rows'] = $this->model_name->total_rows();
/*Model Function*/
function total_rows(){
    return $this->db->count_all('table_name'); #will return the no. of rows in integer    
}
```

Missing required config in Pagination:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Define the CSS, JS files with absolute path always:

```
<link href="<?=base_url()?>css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Last one `print_r` your result in your controller to assure you are getting the values correctly:

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('recipe', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
echo "<pre>";print_r( $data['records'] );die;
```

Comment: [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

does this imply that there were no results returned?

Comment: Yes. Post your model in your question. @user2855169

Comment: Question edited, changes applied.

Row_data is empty. If this was a problem with my table, shouldnt it have posted an db_error or any error at all.